# Simple MySQL select taking too much time

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, count

I am having following simple query, but its taking too much time (.5 seconds/half of a second), I am unable to find the reason. I want to improve the performance of Search.

**Title**

*VARCHAR (50), Collation = latin1_general_ci, NULL allowed, MySQL Engine: MyISAM*

*Number of record in Product table: 163129*

**CatID**

*Foreign Key (int) From Category table*

I already have tried this Optimize statement

---

```
OPTIMIZE table Product
```

---

Here is the simple query.

---

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
Product
WHERE 
CatID=123 
AND Title = 'abc xyz'
```

---

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `explain` to see where you need an index.

Comment: Here is the EXPLAIN output. Not sure how can this help me
- - 
http://postimg.org/image/po6lp2dv9/
- -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking more time meaning the table is not properly indexed and probably doing full table scan.

For this particular query a covering index would be useful

```
alter table Product add index cat_title_idx(CatID,Title);
```

Make sure to take a backup of the table before applying the index.

Comment: If `Title` is too big to be indexed, at least add `INDEX(CatID)`; that would help some.

Comment: Thanks Abhik Chakarborty and Rick James. Indexing did the trick.